# How to translate and what could cause characters such as å¿è€

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, encoding

**Goal:**
I only use select statements with the dbs I have access to.
One of the columns is supposed to store legible english sentences but there are values with strange characters. I would like to find a way to translate those special characters to legible characters

**My question is two fold:**

1. Can I translate the following string to a legible format all stored data is basically lost in translation
2. How can I ensure that the data is stored correctly?

*Column Collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS*

*Column Data Type: NVARCHAR(300)*

**Data Examples:**

å¿è€

ÐžÐ±Ð°Ð¶Ð´Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ñ Ð·Ð°

Comment: The problem here  appears that, at some point, the code pages of your data was incorrect. How the data got to that state is impossible to know, as you don't explain *how* you `INSERT`/`UPDATE` your data in SQL Server. Most likely this has happened when in imported the data via your ETL process, and used the wrong code page, or in your application layer. Once, however, you got the code page wrong, you can't recover the data; it's already been lost.

Comment: `ÐžÐ±Ð` looks suspiciously like UTF8 *bytes* stored as individual characters in a UTF16 field. Someone tried to "fix' what didn't need fixing and converted the original text into UTF8 bytes then stored those bytes as individual characters in the database. Latin characters above 127 need two bytes in UTF8, the first of which can be `110xxxxx`. And `Ð` is `11010000`, a valid first byte in that range.

Comment: That column wasn't meant to contain English characters, even without the obvious bug. Unless ... the reverse bug occured too? Two US-ASCII bytes were converted into one UTF16 value, hence the `å` and `¿` values? Then someone tried to *reverse* the problem by trying to convert the mangled bytes into characters, then into UTF8?

Comment: How were those values inserted? Which SQL Server version are you using? SQL Server 2019 supports UTF8 for *varchar* fields (it's not needed for nvarchar). Perhaps the client code tried storing UTF8 in the wrong field? Or perhaps this was simply bad code that mishandled Unicode?

Comment: @pan Using SQL Server 2017. Unfortunately I have no visibility on either the client code or how the data was inserted. Is this an encoding issue during the insert?

Comment: @RogerSteinberg there is really know way to know for sure from just looking at the data, we would need to see the original code that inserted the data. It was clearly encoded incorrectly, possibly multiple times. So the data is pretty much garbage at this point, there is no hope to reverse it without knowing all the steps it went through.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "*looks suspiciously like UTF8 bytes stored as individual characters in a UTF16 field*" -  `å¿è€` does not represent a valid UTF-8 byte sequence (ALMOST though - the `è` would be invalid in this context). `ÐžÐ±Ð°Ð¶Ð´Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ñ Ð·Ð°` also does not *entirely* represent a valid UTF-8 byte sequence, either (ALMOST though - the `Ñ` would be invalid in this context)

Comment: `ÐÐ±Ð°Ð¶Ð´Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ñ Ð·Ð°` is `cp1252` appearance of UTF8-encoded  Cyrillic `Обаждания за` (something like `Calls for` in Russian). However, I can't understand what a mojibake could be `å¿è€`…

Comment: Python example `'ĐžĐ±Đ°Đ¶Đ´Đ°Đ˝Đ¸ŃŹ Đ·Đ°'.encode('cp1250').decode('utf-8')` returns `'Обаждания за'`…

Comment: @RemyLebeau that's why I suspect *multiple* encoding bugs, both storing UTF8 bytes in the nvarchar column and possible the reverse - reading the bytes and trying to construct proper text again? Or perhaps using the 8wrong* codepage?

Comment: @JosefZ that's why I suspect two bugs, one storing UTF8 bytes as individual characters and another, trying to store either ASCII with the wrong codepage, or trying to convert the stored bytes back into text. Perhaps `å¿è€` is the result of storing CP1250 bytes using the Latin1 codepage? It's not enough to attempt to fix that text with reversing the encoding when each line has *different* encodings

Comment: @RogerSteinberg tell whoever wrote that client to fix the bug and recover the text. There are at least two different *bad* encoding attempts involved. Are you going to try decoding every line in two different ways trying to find out what's wrong? What if there are even more encodings involved? SQL Server doesn't need special treatment to store Unicode text and SO is the proof - it's an ASP.NET site storing data in SQL Server. Whoever wrote the client *had to explicitly write code to mangle the text*, they couldn't have produced those characters otherwise

Comment: @RogerSteinberg perhaps they don't know what Unicode and UTF8 are, so they thought they had to store the UTF8 *bytes* instead of using the strings in a query. There are several questions in SO from either PHP, Python 2, R, even C-on-Linux developers that encounter Unicode for the first time and think that UTF8 is some special escape sequence, or that storing Unicode in a database requires some special kind of encoding. There are far fewer such questions from Python 3, Java, Javascript or .NET devs, where strings are Unicode natively

Comment: @RogerSteinberg if I had to guess I'd say the client was written using string concatenation for SQL, in PHP or Python 2 by developers that never had to handle multilingual text and used hard-coded codepages in their code. And/Or the client runs on Linux - *Linux* doesn't use Unicode natively, strings are supposed to be just bytes whose meaning is controlled by the locale settings in eg LC_ALL. Servers may specify UTF8 there but *end users* typically pick their locale's codepage. So when that client had to store non-local text, nobody noticed and the data was mangled, hence the `å¿è€` values

Comment: @RogerSteinberg when they did notice, not knowing about Unicode, they thought they needed to encode the text in UTF8, thus producing `ÐÐ±Ð°Ð¶Ð´Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ñ Ð·Ð°`.  If the code used parameterized/server-bound queries (the terms differ from language to language) no code would be necessary, the driver itself would have sent the strings as separate parameters in the RPC call to the server. It's still possible to mangle this by specifying the wrong parameter type, or overriding the driver's automatic codepage translation and specifying an explicit codepage for a parameter.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for precise and thorough answer

Comment: @RogerSteinberg those were just guesses, and JosefZ specified the actual codepage. We expect you to tell us what actually happened.

Comment: @JosefZ thank you! for the mojibake å¿è€ its from a sensitive string so i only took the first 6 characters which explains why it has no meaning

Comment: @sent your responses to the front end team. will see what they say

Answer (score 0):

Use prefix of ‘N’ While you Enter to table

Insert Into TownMessage_Tbl Values (elanat=N' + Elanat +"')

Comment: If the OP had omitted the `N` prefix they wouldn't have values like they do, they would have `?`s. This is a code page issue.